# Java 8 formatted date input

Tags: java, java-8

I use this code to format a formatted text field to enter month & day:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd");
DateFormatter df = new DateFormatter(sdf);
DefaultFormatterFactory ddf = new DefaultFormatterFactory(df, df, df, df);
datumTextField.setValue(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
datumTextField.setFormatterFactory(ddf);
```

When an invalid date is entered, eg. 13.10, a magican changes it to 1.10 after this line:

```
DateOfAdding = datumTextField.getText();
```

so the DateOfAddig value is 1.10.

How to turm the magican off?

Comment: A *magician*...? It just looks like the field is just returning the closest approximation to a valid date that it can. Describe more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Then describe the **exact** steps you take and the **exact** behavior that your program displays. Supplement your description with screenshots if necessary.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to call the `SimpleDateFormat`'s [`setLenient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) method with `false` as a parameter so that the underlying Calendar used for parsing is set to non-lenient.

A non-lenient calendar will refuse field values that aren't in the expected range for this field, rather than accepting them and modifying other fields to make sense of them : in your case the month was rolled-over 12 and reached 1, while the year was increased by 1 and probably reached 1971 rather than the default-when-unspecified 1970.

From the [`Calendar`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) :

> Leniency
>
> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.
>
> When a Calendar is in non-lenient mode, it throws an exception if there is any inconsistency in its calendar fields. For example, a GregorianCalendar always produces DAY_OF_MONTH values between 1 and the length of the month. A non-lenient GregorianCalendar throws an exception upon calculating its time or calendar field values if any out-of-range field value has been set.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay.parse( 
    "12.31" , 
     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM.dd" ) 
)
```

Catch [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) for invalid input.

## `java.time.MonthDay`

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy classes seen in the Question.

Among the java.time classes is [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html), just what you need.

I suggest collecting input as two different numbers.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( x , y ) ;
```

If you insist, you can collect input as a combined string and [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). If so I suggest you and your user use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `--MM-DD`.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "--12-31" ) ;
```

Or define a pattern using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM.dd" ) ;
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to detect invalid inputs.

```
String input = "13.10" ;  // Invalid input. Month must be 1-12.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM.dd" ) ;
MonthDay md = null ;
try 
{
    md = MonthDay.parse( input , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) { 
    // … handle error …
    System.out.println( "Invalid input: " + input ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/tDT8oQ).

> Invalid input: 13.10
>
> e: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '13.10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain MonthDay from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=13, DayOfMonth=10},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
>
> md.toString(): null

Comment: Yup, better solution than mine especially since the question has the [tag:java-8] tag